# Working with multiple MySQL rows and For Loop - not working

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop

I have trying to print the top 3 recent posts (rows) from MySQL. I am using a `for loop` that counts 3 times to prints out 3 DIVS for each post (row). **Then I use `for each` loop to print out the MySQL row. The problem is I am printing out all three rows inside one DIV.**

**Here is the code:**

```
 <!-- Content Body Container -->
<div class="content-body" class="container-fluid">
  <div id="content-container">

    <?php
    $result = doSql("SELECT `gamereviews`.`reviewContent` FROM `gamereviews` ORDER BY `gamereviews`.`dateOfReview` DESC LIMIT 3");
    ?>

    <?php
      for($i = 1; $i<=3; $i++) {
    ?>
      <div id="outer-box">
        <div id="postImage-wrapper">
          image
        </div>
        <div id="postContent-wrapper">
          <h3> This is an Example post </h3>
          <span id="postInfo-wrapper">Author | 22/10/2015 | Xbox | 3 Comments</span><br />
          <?php
          if($result && mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)>0) {
            foreach($result as $row) {
              echo '<div onclick="alert(\''.$row['reviewContent'].'\');">'.substr($row['reviewContent'], 0, 300).'</div>';
            //  echo $row['reviewContent']. '<br /><br />';
            }
          }
          ?>
        </div>

        <div id="postRating-wrapper">
          7.7
        </div>
      </div>


  <?php
    }
    ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

**How can I print each MySQL row into each DIV created by for loop? Any ideas?**

**UPDATE:**

**Here are the results:**
https://gyazo.com/5a91ed6a3837c0293c7504525ef86681

As you can see, all the rows are printed in the first DIV. That is, the first time for loop is run, it printed out all the rows inside it. But the SECOND time for loop is run, it doesn't print out anything inside the second div. It SHOULD print out the SECOND row from mysql in the SECOND DIV and FIRST row of mysql in FIRST DIV. And THIRD row of mysql in THIRD DIV

Comment: which div you want to repeat??

Comment: None. The divs are working, printing out 3 divs. The for each statement is also working, but it prints out 3 rows inside the first div that is created. I want each of the 3 rows to be printed out separately in three divs. So each post div has a row (article) with a total of three post divs. Any ideas?

Comment: you want repeat your first div 3 times?? if so whuch is that div??

Comment: I have added a screenshot of what the page currently looks like. As you can see, all the rows are printed in the first DIV. That is, the first time for loop is run, it printed out all the rows inside it. But the SECOND time for loop is run, it doesn't print out anything inside the second div. It SHOULD print out the SECOND row from mysql in the SECOND DIV and FIRST row of mysql in FIRST DIV. And THIRD row of mysql in THIRD DIV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I get your question right you shouldn't be using for in the first place
Print three divs with one result in it:

```
    <?php
$counter = 0;
    if($result && mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)>0)
            foreach($result as $row) :
        if($counter >= 3)
            break;
        ?>
        <div id="outer-box">
            <div id="postImage-wrapper">
                image
            </div>
            <div id="postContent-wrapper">
                <h3> This is an Example post </h3>
                <span id="postInfo-wrapper">Author | 22/10/2015 | Xbox | 3 Comments</span><br />
                <?php
                echo '<div onclick="alert(\''.$row['reviewContent'].'\');">'.substr($row['reviewContent'], 0, 300).'</div>';
                //  echo $row['reviewContent']. '<br /><br />';
                ?>
            </div>

            <div id="postRating-wrapper">
                7.7
            </div>
        </div>


        <?php
    $counter++;
    endforeach;
    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But I don't understand why you haven't used  braces for your for and for each loop?

Comment: I dont like braces becouse at times you dont know what statement ends where. endforeach; tells you clearly where foreach ends :).

Comment: So is the following one statement: foreach($result as $row) :     if($counter >= 3)   break; And what does colon ':' mean here?

Comment: Colon is like opening brace '{', now script is looking for closing brace '}'. When u use colon php searches for end{{statement_here}} in foreach example its endforeach;

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this.

```
  <?php
      if($result && mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)>0) {
           $i = 1;
        foreach($result as $row) { ?>
         <div id="outer-box">
             <div id="postImage-wrapper">
                 image
             </div>
           <div id="postContent-wrapper">
              <h3> This is an Example post </h3>
              <span id="postInfo-wrapper">Author | 22/10/2015 | Xbox | 3 Comments</span><br />

              <?php  echo '<div onclick="alert(\''.$row['reviewContent'].'\');">'.substr($row['reviewContent'], 0, 300).'</div>';
       ?>
           </div>

        </div>

        <div id="postRating-wrapper">
            7.7
        </div>

     <?php

      if($i == 3)
            break;
      $i++;
      }// end of foreach
      }// end of if()
      ?>
```